# Get post-id after FB.ui() share

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, fb.ui

I need to get `post-id` after user clicks on the `share` button. My code so far:

```
$("#share").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'developers.facebook.com',
  }, function(response){
    if(response && !response.error_code) {
      console.log(response); // => []
    } else {
      alert('err');
    }
  });
});
```

After content is successfully shared, the response I get is an empty array with no data. How can I get the `post-id` of `share` post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) for information about the response:

> Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story.

Meaning, you will only get the post-/object-id if the user is authorized with the `publish_actions` permission.

Comment: Thank you, just tested and you are right. After adding publish_actions permission I got post-id in response.